# Custom Way to Wait for all thread to complete in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

After Starting the thread object

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

i need to wait for the finalization of both threads using the join() method(the most common way).

Like this.

```
try {
      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

All the tutorial i see uses some inbuilt method for finalization of threads.

Is there a way to wait for thread finalization without using any inbuilt method like join or executor ?

Comment: `"s there a way to wait for thread finalization without using any inbuilt method ?"` -- This begs the question -- why not use the excellent concurrency classes?

Comment: No, there is not. You can never know if thread is has completed execution  in other threads except by using thread methods, such as `join`.

Comment: @zch You can know if thread has completed execution or not by looking at it's State. `join` is not needed for that

Comment: @AnkurAnand, you are still using Thread methods than. And busy waiting.

Comment: Whatever you do, continuous polling, as suggested by one of the current answers, is **not** a viable or scalable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Thread has a state. NEW , RUNNABLE , BLOCKED , WAITING , TIMED_WAITING , or
TERMINATED

TERMINATED is a state that you can look for every thread with `thread.getState()` method, which is the state of thread once it finish execution

```
// 2 Thread Object 
            Thread threads[] = new Thread[2];
            // store Thread Statuses
            Thread.State status[] = new Thread.State[2];
```

Since All Thread have state. Before starting thread store
their state

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        status[i] = threads[i].getState();
                }
```

Once you start the thread
                The finished Thread has a state of Terminated, you can use it to 
                and write your own check for finalization

```
    // custom way for finalization of the threads
     boolean finish = false; // initially all non finised 
     while(!finish) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (threads[i].getState() != status[i]) {
                    status[i] = threads[i].getState();
                    }
                }
            finish = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            finish = finish && (threads[i].getState() ==
                                State.TERMINATED);
                }
 }
```